# SSIS, read the subcomponent parameter in the event handler after fireinformation

Tags: ssis, eventhandler

I'm looking for a way to read in the event handler tab, the SubComponent parameter that is sent as you call the method FireIformation or FireWarning or FireError.

On the MSDN website, they say this about the subcomponent :

"Several of the events have a subComponent parameter that allows for even greater granularity in event source identification."

On this example :

```
    ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(10, "SubComponent here...", "Informative text here...", "", 0, fireAgain);
```

I'm able to catch the information on the event handler tab but I've checked on all the system variables, none of them seem to contain my value.

Need help here,

Thanks,